# Can a content type have default input in fields

Tags: 6, nodes, users

Is there a way for a user to add new content and have some of the fields already pre populated with default text/input.

That way the user can amend what changes are required for a node without having to copy and paste what will be very similar details into the add content screen node/add/[content type]?

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes almost all fields have a section to add default content.
Go to "Structure" > "Content Types" > Your content type > "Manage Fields" then select edit on the field that you want to add the default text to

Comment: hi pete80, I've tried going to admin/content/node-type/no-size-options(my content type)/fields and have the 'Manage Fields' page showing, however i can see no edit again the field names, just label / Name / Type / Operations. There is no edit available in any Operations. Could this be missing from Drupal 6? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Sorry I didnt realise it was for 6 in that case you can use a hook_form_alter in a custom module or this module will help for the body field https://www.drupal.org/project/DefaultTextForNode

Comment: Thanks pete80, sorry did try and put a tag on for 'Drupal6' but the system rejected it. That module does exactly what i need. Not sure if a Mod can give you a vote, because apparently i'm too young to be able. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for prepopulate...

https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate

Although that may not be workable for all forms as you wish, but when I used it, it worked as expected.

This module allows you to enter field names and their default value on a URL and the module take that data and puts it in the input fields as default.